# How to make prettyphoto jquery lightbox responsive using Bootstrap v2.3.1

Tags: responsive-design, lightbox

I have implemented lightbox in my responsive site using [jquery prettyphoto lightbox](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone#prettyPhoto) and make my inline content to display inside lightbox.How to make the lightbox as responsive

```
    <a href="#inline-1" rel="prettyPhoto" >Prettyphoto lightbox</a>

   <div id="inline-1" class="hide">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
```